# Print statement repeating twice instead of once in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I've created a python program that generates secure password phrases, I've made it so that the user can decide whether or not to print their password to a text file with the `raw_input` function. I've also made it so that the program repeats itself if the user decides to enter input that is unrecognized by the program. I've been stumped on this one issue though. Below is the code and under is my explanation of the problem.

```
if writeyn == 'Y' or writeyn == 'y' or writeyn == 'yes' or writeyn == 'Yes':
    print('Written to passwords.txt')
    f = open("passwords.txt", "a+") # "append"
    f.write(passtype + " - " + mypw)

if writeyn == 'n' or writeyn == 'N' or writeyn == 'no' or writeyn == 'No':
    print('Writting Stopped.')

while writeyn != 'n' or writeyn != 'N' or writeyn != 'no' or writeyn != 'No' or writeyn != 'Y' or writeyn != 'y' or writeyn != 'yes' or writeyn != 'Yes':
     writeyn = raw_input("Invalid Input; " + "\nWould you like to write your password to a text file? Y or n")
     writeyn = writeyn.strip()
     if writeyn == 'n' or writeyn == 'N' or writeyn == 'no' or writeyn == 'No':
         print 'Writing Stopped.'
         break
     elif writeyn == 'Y' or writeyn == 'y' or writeyn == 'yes' or writeyn == 'Yes':
         print('Written to passwords.txt')
         f = open("passwords.txt", "a+")
         f.write(passtype + " - " + mypw)
         break
```

When I run the program inside Terminal I get the following output which is shown in the link below.

[print statement repeats twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJCx9.png)

Instead of the `print 'Writing Stopped.` printing once when the user specifies that they would not like to write the password to the passwords.txt file it instead repeats twice. This also applies to the `print('Written to passwords.txt')`.
I've looked at whitespace to see if that was the issue but it seems like it isn't. Does anyone know what's causing the program to do this?

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Beyond the other advice, I find using `writeyn.lower() in ['n','no','y','yes']` to be a lot easier to read than a string of conditionals. lower() on a string will put it into lowercase so half of your cases disappear. The x in [x,y,z] pattern returns true if x is contained in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you connect the logical comparisons in

```
while writeyn != 'n' or writeyn != 'N' or writeyn != 'no' or writeyn != 'No' or writeyn != 'Y' or writeyn != 'y' or writeyn != 'yes' or writeyn != 'Yes':
```

According to your screenshot you entered "n". So the comparison

```
writeyn != 'n'
```

is False, but

```
writeyn != 'N'
```

is True. Since you connect them all with OR, the final result is true and you enter the while loop (causing the dialog to reappear).

To fix it I would suggest using

```
while not (writeyn == 'n' or writeyn == 'N' or writeyn == 'no' or writeyn == 'No' or writeyn == 'Y' or writeyn == 'y' or writeyn == 'yes' or writeyn == 'Yes'):
```

Comment: @TheoretiCAL Yes, but his code snipped is incomplete imo. The screenshot shows additional lines being printed (like the lines containing StackOverflow). That source code is not shown. The first time "Would you like to write your password to a text file" is printed is not part of the above code snipped. But based on his question I think it is clear what he is trying to do. He wants the user to enter a valid answer and if the answer is invalid, he wants to enter the while loop.

Comment: The comparison writeyn != 'n' is False because 'n'=='n'. The comparison writeyn != 'N' is True because 'N'!='n'.

Comment: As for the string type. The documtation of raw_input says: raw_input([prompt])
If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Comment: Just saw what you meant, was confused for a second but now the error makes sense. I've now restricted the input to Y or n solely. The additional y, yes, and etc just raises to many problems. Thanks for your help.